# Table rows to array after Curl

Tags: php, arrays, dom, curl, xpath

I am looking for a way with PHP to store HTML Table rows into an array with each column value into a distinctive array value.

First of all I have a full HTML page I got from a curl function. In this page I have a table with a specific ID (`example_table`).

How can I choose this table and then put each table value into an 2 coordinate array?

```
<table id="example_table">
    <tr><td>A1</td><td>B1</td><td>C1</td><td>D1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>A2</td><td>B2</td><td>C2</td><td>D2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>A3</td><td>B3</td><td>C3</td><td>D3</td></tr>
</table>
```

The resulting array that would work like this:

```
array_example[2][3] = D3
```

//Edit :

the HTML code I get from the curl is the following :

```
<table style="width: 95%; border-collapse: collapse" id="itemDetails"> 
       <tbody>
        <tr> 
         <td class="photo" style="width: 150px; text-align: center; padding: 16px 0 10px 0; vertical-align: top; font-size: 12px; line-height: 18px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif"> <a href="https://www.amazon.fr/gp/r.html?C=11II60L0IUDTQ&amp;K=A37E83YVOBN2AM&amp;R=JC53DV4YW1VB&amp;T=C&amp;U=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.fr%2Fdp%2FB003629R5S%2Fref%3Dpe_386181_40444391_TE_item_image&amp;A=UOK26PXWANT3G9FAME6Z7XWZJVWA&amp;H=6B71WXRFQA1P9GFWS8UJRWK0VRAA&amp;ref_=pe_386181_40444391_TE_item_image" title="B003629R5S" style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(0, 102, 153); font: 12px/ 16px Arial, sans-serif"> <img id="asin" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31FSVzCchgL._SCLZZZZZZZ__SY115_SX115_.jpg" style="border: 0"> </a> </td> 
         <td class="name" style="color: rgb(102, 102, 102); padding: 10px 0 0 0; vertical-align: top; font-size: 12px; line-height: 18px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif"> <a href="https://www.amazon.fr/gp/r.html?C=11II60L0IUDTQ&amp;K=A37E83YVOBN2AM&amp;R=JC53DV4YW1VB&amp;T=C&amp;U=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.fr%2Fdp%2FB003629R5S%2Fref%3Dpe_386181_40444391_TE_item&amp;A=GNBXWEPQKFU3GEGJBGMMWYKA3K4A&amp;H=RXNWUWDFVKS3LQE1FENOQS4VDXCA&amp;ref_=pe_386181_40444391_TE_item" style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(0, 102, 153); font: 12px/ 16px Arial, sans-serif"> Brabantia Lot de 12 rouleaux de 10 sacs poubelle Type L 45 l </a> <br> Etat : Neuf <br> Vendu par <a href="https://www.amazon.fr/gp/r.html?C=11II60L0IUDTQ&amp;K=A37E83YVOBN2AM&amp;R=JC53DV4YW1VB&amp;T=C&amp;U=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.fr%2Fgp%2Fhelp%2Fseller%2Fhome.html%2Fref%3Dpe_386181_40444391_TE_seller%3Fie%3DUTF8%26seller%3DA2ANA7NET4TQ0F&amp;A=AJJRA9DQK9EDVNDQDNAULH4KOC4A&amp;H=XH19ITMSWA3KJ0PSBTHLNQAFYAAA&amp;ref_=pe_386181_40444391_TE_seller" style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(0, 102, 153); font: 12px/ 16px Arial, sans-serif">Perfect Groceries</a> <br> <a href="https://www.amazon.fr/gp/r.html?C=11II60L0IUDTQ&amp;K=A37E83YVOBN2AM&amp;R=JC53DV4YW1VB&amp;T=C&amp;U=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.fr%2Fexpedieparamazon%3Fref_%3Dpe_386181_40444391_TE_helpfba&amp;A=KEYAA7VCZNWVKEA7P2LYC49LKQMA&amp;H=W03OAAPQITJM5WD6MC5LG21OLVIA&amp;ref_=pe_386181_40444391_TE_helpfba" style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(0, 102, 153); font: 12px/ 16px Arial, sans-serif">Expédié par Amazon</a> <br> 
          <div style="vertical-align: top; align=center;"> 
           <table border="0" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: separate"> 
            <tbody style="vertical-align: bottom;"> 
             <tr> 
              <td style="vertical-align: top; font-size: 12px; line-height: 18px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif"> </td> 
              <td style="vertical-align: top; font-size: 12px; line-height: 18px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif"> <a href="https://www.amazon.fr/gp/r.html?C=11II60L0IUDTQ&amp;K=A37E83YVOBN2AM&amp;R=JC53DV4YW1VB&amp;T=C&amp;U=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.fr%3A80%2Fgp%2Fredirect.html%2Fref%3Dpe_386181_40444391_cm_sw_cl_fa_doce%2F280-1861239-2544346%3F_encoding%3DUTF8%26location%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.facebook.com%252Fdialog%252Ffeed%253Fapp_id%253D164734381262%2526caption%253D%2526display%253Dpopup%2526link%253Dhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.amazon.fr%25252Fdp%25252FB003629R5S%25252Fref%25253Dcm_sw_r_fa_doce%2526name%253D%2526picture%253Dhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fecx.images-amazon.com%25252Fimages%25252FI%25252F31FSVzCchgL._SCLZZZZZZZ__SY115_SX115_.jpg%2526redirect_uri%253Dhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.amazon.fr%25252Fdp%25252FB003629R5S%25252Fref%25253Dcm_sw_r_fa_doce%26source%3Dstandards%26token%3D6BD0FB927CC51E76FF446584B1040F70EA7E88E1&amp;A=O66YJALVI4AECB8UEEBF4NGUHQQA&amp;H=PAUAVYQX28VPMP9DQELUI7PJWJWA&amp;ref_=pe_386181_40444391_cm_sw_cl_fa_doce" title="Facebook" style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(0, 102, 153); font: 12px/ 16px Arial, sans-serif"> <img src="http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/08/x-locale/personalization/live-meter/facebook._V15055984_.gif" width="16" alt="Facebook" style="vertical-align: middle; border: 0" height="16" border="0"> </a> </td> 
              <td style="vertical-align: top; font-size: 12px; line-height: 18px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif"> <a href="https://www.amazon.fr/gp/r.html?C=11II60L0IUDTQ&amp;K=A37E83YVOBN2AM&amp;R=JC53DV4YW1VB&amp;T=C&amp;U=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.fr%3A80%2Fgp%2Fredirect.html%2Fref%3Dpe_386181_40444391_cm_sw_cl_tw_doce%2F280-1861239-2544346%3F_encoding%3DUTF8%26location%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Ftwitter.com%252Fshare%253Fcount%253Dnone%2526original_referer%253Dhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.amazon.fr%25252Fdp%25252FB003629R5S%25252Fref%25253Dcm_sw_r_tw_doce%2526related%253Damazon%25252Camazondeals%25252Camazonmp3%2526text%253DBrabantia%252520Lot%252520de%25252012%252520rouleaux%252520de%25252010%252520sacs%252520poubelle%252520Type%252520L%25252045%252520l%252520sur%252520Amazon%2526twitterURL%253Dhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.amazon.fr%25252Fdp%25252FB003629R5S%25252Fref%25253Dcm_sw_r_tw_doce%2526via%253Damazon%26source%3Dstandards%26token%3D7A1A4AE8F6CE0BD277D8295E58702D283F329C0F&amp;A=KPDO6A0PIPKRQL84ARGCMAOOCASA&amp;H=TA6BYC0F3HFJPCCQIIOCPYIGFAGA&amp;ref_=pe_386181_40444391_cm_sw_cl_tw_doce" title="Twitter" style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(0, 102, 153); font: 12px/ 16px Arial, sans-serif"> <img src="http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/08/x-locale/communities/social/twitter._V388040480_.gif" width="16" alt="Twitter" style="vertical-align: middle; border: 0" height="16" border="0"> </a> </td> 
              <td style="vertical-align: top; font-size: 12px; line-height: 18px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif"> <a href="https://www.amazon.fr/gp/r.html?C=11II60L0IUDTQ&amp;K=A37E83YVOBN2AM&amp;R=JC53DV4YW1VB&amp;T=C&amp;U=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.fr%3A80%2Fgp%2Fredirect.html%2Fref%3Dpe_386181_40444391_cm_sw_cl_pi_doce%2F280-1861239-2544346%3F_encoding%3DUTF8%26location%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fpinterest.com%252Fpin%252Fcreate%252Fbutton%252F%253Fdescription%253DBrabantia%252520Lot%252520de%25252012%252520rouleaux%252520de%25252010%252520sacs%252520poubelle%252520Type%252520L%25252045%252520l%252520sur%252520Amazon%25252C%252520http%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.amazon.fr%25252Fdp%25252FB003629R5S%25252Fref%25253Dcm_sw_r_pi_doce%2526is_video%253Dfalse%2526media%253Dhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fecx.images-amazon.com%25252Fimages%25252FI%25252F31FSVzCchgL._SCLZZZZZZZ__SY115_SX115_.jpg%2526title%253D%2526url%253Dhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.amazon.fr%25252Fdp%25252FB003629R5S%25252Fref%25253Dcm_sw_r_pi_doce%26source%3Dstandards%26token%3D9F58B366258E1A8B5259E9BEF3482E02341F42D3&amp;A=RDONF9RAZWJSW6DTDZM6CAUCAXAA&amp;H=GEAUNFZ4QS9J5KE00AWBWWLX81UA&amp;ref_=pe_386181_40444391_cm_sw_cl_pi_doce" title="Pinterest" style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(0, 102, 153); font: 12px/ 16px Arial, sans-serif"> <img src="http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/08/x-locale/communities/social/pinterest._V389372180_.png" width="16" alt="Pinterest" style="vertical-align: middle; border: 0" height="16" border="0"> </a> </td> 
             </tr> 
            </tbody> 
           </table> 
          </div> </td> 
         <td class="price" style="width: 80px; text-align: right; font-size: 14px; padding: 10px 10px 0 0; vertical-align: top; line-height: 18px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif"> <strong>EUR 59,99</strong> <br> </td> 
        </tr> 
       </tbody>
      </table>
```

Comment: Is that an accurate representation of the table i.e. no `id=""` no `<input>` fields etc

Comment: You have not ids inside each td and tr but you have some html inside some of the table values.

Comment: Where do you want to do the data collection, before you send that table to the browser or after it has been sent to the browsewr? Maybe you should show the code that gets this table

Comment: The code works this way : I have a curl function that gets me some html content. Inside this content I have the table I described. And I would like to extract the table values into a 2 dimensional arrays. I'll add the details of the table into the initial post.

Comment: You've got the awkward situation of having a lot of tags that are nested inside of the same tag. Meaning it's gonna be a nightmare to come up with a regex to parse that out. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table data cells in you example do not have any text content except some whitespaces. They have child elements with attributes however so I imagine you would like to extract their data.

Use DOM+Xpath. DOM can load HTML (it will repair errors and might change the structure). `DOMXpath::evaluate()` allows you to fetch node lists and scalar values from a DOM. Xpath expressions are used to address nodes inside the DOM.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHtml($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$result = [];
foreach($xpath->evaluate('//table[@id="itemDetails"]//table/tbody/tr') as $tr) {
  $row = [];
  foreach ($xpath->evaluate('td[a]', $tr) as $td) {
    $row[] = [
      'href' => $xpath->evaluate('string(a/@href)', $td),
      'image' => $xpath->evaluate('string(a/img/@src)', $td),
      'text' => $xpath->evaluate('string(a/img/@alt)', $td)
    ];
  }
  $result[] = $row; 
}

var_dump($result);
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["href"]=>
      string(908) "https://www...."
      ["image"]=>
      string(103) "http://g-ecx..."
      ["text"]=>
      string(8) "Facebook"
    }
    [1]=>...
```